# Count occurrences in specific column ranges and return factor variable, R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data like this:

```
df<-structure(list(levels_incised___1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___2 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___4 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___5 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___6 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___7 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___8 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___9 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___10 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___11 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___12 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___13 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___14 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___15 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___16 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___18 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___20 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), levels_incised___22 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), levels_incised___23 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), levels_incised___24 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1), levels_incised___25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), levels_incised___26 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1), levels_incised___27 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), levels_incised___28 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1), levels_incised___29 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), levels_incised___30 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0), levels_incised___31 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

That originally came from this Redcap input where each button was one of those columns:
[image]

And I need to create a column at the end (lets call it Level) with these possible inputs:

- Cervical  (any of the c buttons)
- Thoracic  (the t's)
- Lumbar (the L's)
- Sacral (sacral)
- Thoracocervical (t's or c's)
- Thoracolumbar (t's or l's)
- Lumbosacral (l's and sacral)

So for instance, the patient in the first row had "1"'s in levels_incised_2 through levels_incised_10... meaning they had values in both the cervical range and the thoracic range.  So that patient should get "Thoracocervical".

The patient in row 2 had 1's in 8 through 15, so they'd only get a "thoracic"

Does anyone know the most straight forward way to accomplish this?

Oh one last detail, there's 100+ other columns so it'd be nice if I could select/name these specific ones to count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to resolve here:

- find a way to convert `levels...#` to one of the `C`/`T`/... categories;
- produce logic to infer based on presence of groups.

I think the first can be done by extracting the number and using `findInterval` to determine with of `C`/`T`/... each column belongs to. From there, we can do some simple `c_across` to find "any" in a group, and `case_when` to get your `Level` labels.

```r
library(dplyr)

# helper function for renaming
func <- function(z) {
  num <- as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", z))
  grp <- c("C","T","L","S","Co","unclear")[findInterval(num, 1+c(0, 7, 19, 24, 29, 30, 31))]
  grp <- paste0(grp, ave(grp, grp, FUN = seq_along))
  # fix those that do not need numbering
  grp[grepl("^Co", grp)] <- "Co"
  grp[grepl("^unc", grp)] <- "unclear"
  grp
}

out <- df %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("levels"), .fn = func) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    anyC = sum(c_across(C1:C7)) > 0, 
    anyT = sum(c_across(T1:T12)) > 0, 
    anyL = sum(c_across(L1:L5)) > 0, 
    anyS = sum(c_across(S1:S5)) > 0
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    Level = case_when(
      anyC & anyT & anyL ~ "More than 2?", 
      anyL & anyS ~ "Lumbosacral", 
      anyT & anyL ~ "Thoracolumbar", 
      anyT & anyC ~ "Thoracocervical", 
      anyS ~ "Sacral", 
      anyL ~ "Lumbar", 
      anyT ~ "Thoracic", 
      anyC ~ "Cervical", 
      TRUE ~ "Nothing?"
    )
  )
out
# # A tibble: 6 x 36
#      C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    T1    T2    T3    T4    T5    T6    T7    T8    T9   T10   T11   T12    L1    L2    L3    L4    L5    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    Co unclear anyC  anyT  anyL  anyS  Level          
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>          
# 1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE Thoracocervical
# 2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE Thoracic       
# 3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0 FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE Thoracic       
# 4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1       0 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  Sacral         
# 5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       0 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  Lumbosacral    
# 6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0       0 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  Lumbosacral    
out$Level
# [1] "Thoracocervical" "Thoracic"        "Thoracic"        "Sacral"          "Lumbosacral"     "Lumbosacral"
```

If you don't want to keep the renaming, then you can combine the `Level` result to your original frame with `cbind(df, Level = out$Level)`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  And added thank you for that final cbind note.  I had a bunch of other code dependent on the original data frame and column names, so that was a plus.

Answer (score 1):

using package [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```
## vertebra codes needed later on
vertebra_codes <- c(
    paste0('C',1:7), paste0('T',1:12),
    paste0('L',1:5), paste0('S',1:5),
    'X', ## for Coccyx
    '-' ## for unknown
)


df %>%
    mutate(
        ## assuming each row is a case:
        case_id = paste0('case_',row_number())
    ) %>% 
    ## reshape the data from wide to long format:
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -case_id,
        names_to = 'level_incised', values_to = 'is_incised'
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        ## remove the redundant 'levels_incised__' prefix:
        level_incised = gsub('.*_','',level_incised),
        ## assign the vertebra corresponding to 'level':
        vertebra = vertebra_codes[as.integer(level_incised)],
        ## assign the spine region (e.g.: all lumbal vert. start with 'L'
        spine_region = substr(vertebra,1,1)
    ) %>%
    filter(is_incised == 1) %>% ## we're interested in incised vert. only
    ## remove replicates (more than one vertebra per spine region affected:
    distinct(case_id, spine_region) %>%
    ## do the counts per case:
    group_by(case_id) %>%
    ## string together the affected regions per case:
    summarise(incised_regions = paste(spine_region, collapse = ','))
```

*result:*

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  case_id incised_regions
  <chr>   <chr>          
1 case_1  C,T            
2 case_2  T              
3 case_3  T              
4 case_4  S,X            
5 case_5  L,S,X          
6 case_6  L,S
```

---

(Note that original `df` remains unchanged throughout the processing pipeline. However you can break up the pipeline by removing the `%>%` operator and inspect the intermediary steps, or assign them to temporary objects.)

---

*extra / for fun:* [example code](https://gist.github.com/1O/65a5ebdddd3aca770ee5b9fa9ebbc7db) to `ggplot` the spine with vertebra status (incised or not) per patient.